# Autocomplete suggestion hiding the AutocompleteTextview Field partially

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I want to know why my autocomplete textview suggestion is hiding the autocomplete textview , i am attaching the picture for better understanding.
[image]

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/current_location"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/round_background_white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:dropDownHeight="80dp"
        android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:dropDownListViewStyle="@style/DropDownListViewStyle"/>
```

Style.xml:

```
<style name="DropDownListViewStyle">
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">2dp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: I don't see it is hiding a textView on the picture. It is visible on the picture

Comment: @VladMatvienko suggestion is coming above autocompltetextview field

Comment: I see it is **below** on the image. Not above.

Comment: suggestion is partially hiding the autocompletetextview field

Comment: @VladMatvienko , i am writing MU in autocompletetextview field , it showing me the dropdown , but when you see closely the dropdown is Hiding the MU partially

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to the custom drawable `round_background_white`.
Make sure you are specifying enough `height` & `padding` in it. 
Also post your `round_background_white` over here.